# Compare vales and find the missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In the following JSON data, A item has "gluten" in the allergyfree string while B item doesn't. I can add a `<h4>Yes</h4>` to A item but I also want to add a `<h4>No</h4>` to B item since it doesn't contain "gluten" in the string. The same goes for the other allergyfree values.

Is there any way to compare the allergyfree strings between A item and B item in the loop, so that if the item has the value, for example, gluten, then print `<h4>Yes</h4>`, if missing, print `<h4>No</h4>`?

```
[{"title":"A Item","allergyfree":"sugar,salt,yeast,wheat,gluten"},{"title":"B Item","allergyfree":"sugar,salt,starch,yeast,wheat,preservatives"}]
```

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: source.json,
    success: function (data) {
        var item_html;

        $(data).each(function (index, item) { 
         var allergyfree = item.allergyfree;           
         if(allergyfree.length !== 0) {

           allergyfree = allergyfree.split(",");

           $.each(allergyfree,function(i,allergy){

            if (?????????????????) 
             {
               $('.'+ allergy).html('<h4>Yes</h4>') 
             }
            else
             { 
               $('.'+ allergy).html('<h4>No</h4>')
             }

           });
          }

        });
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

HTML

```
    <table>
       <tr><th colspan="3">A Item</th></tr>
       <tr><td class="gluten"></td>
       <td class="sugar"></td>
       <td class="yeast"></td></tr>
   </table>


    <table>
       <tr><th colspan="3">B Item</th></tr>
       <tr><td class="gluten"></td>
       <td class="sugar"></td>
       <td class="yeast"></td></tr>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$.inArray function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) it returns position of item in array and -1 if item is not present :

```
if ($.inArray(alergy,allergyfree)!=-1)
```