# $.inArray function doesn't return "-1" if item isn't present

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Please take a look at this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/118/)**. Why isn't B item returning `-1` given that it doesn't have the value "gluten" in the string `allergyfree`?

Here's the JSON file:

```
[{"title":"A","allergyfree":"sugar,salt,yeast,wheat,gluten"},{"title":"B","allergyfree":"sugar,salt,starch,yeast,wheat,preservatives"}]
```

Script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url.json",
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) { 
         var title = item.title;
         var allergyfree = item.allergyfree;           
         if(allergyfree.length !== 0) {

           allergyfree = allergyfree.split(",");

           $.each(allergyfree,function(i,allergy){

            $('.'+title+allergy).append(jQuery.inArray(allergy, allergyfree));

           });
          }

        });
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

I ask this question because I have a problem to check whether the value is present in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833897/compare-vales-and-find-the-missing) and someone suggests using `inArray` function, but it isn't working.

Comment: @WesleyMurch, this is just a demonstration to find out if it really returns a number when values aren't present. I want to find out why this statement `if ($.inArray(allergy,allergyfree)!=-1)` isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug (or just have a look at the response) you will find that your ajax request is not returning an entry for `B` and `gluten`.  So `inArray` is never called for that combination of `title` and `allergy`.  That is why the spot for that is left empty.

In fact, your code guarentees that you will never have a case where `inArray` does not find an entry.  **You are searching for each element in the array within that same array.**  So clearly the element will always be found.

---

What you should be doing instead is looping over a list of all allergies you care about and then checking those in the result of your request.  Something like this:

```
var allergies = ["gluten", "yeast"];

$.ajax({
    /* ... */

    $.each(allergies,function(i,allergy){
        $('.'+title+allergy).append(jQuery.inArray(allergy, allergyfree));
    });

    /* ... */
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/119/

Comment: Thank you. Is there still a way to make a if statement like `if($.inArray(allergy,allergyfree) !== null) {$('.'+title+allergy).html('Yes') } else {$('.'+title+allergy).html('No') }` so that when `gluten` isn't present in `B`, it will show "No"?

Comment: @user35295 Answer updated to explain how to do what I believe you are trying to do.